# How to start Scala Play application on Bluemix?

Tags: scala, playframework, ibm-cloud

I have basic Scala application on Play framework and I try to deploy it to IBM Bluemix. During deployment it shows next:

```
an instance of the app crashed: failed to accept connections within health check timeout
exit status: -1, CRASHED
```

My manifest.yml

```
applications:
- path: ./target/universal/scala-bluemix-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip  
memory: 512M
instances: 1
domain: eu-gb.mybluemix.net
name: TestApp1WithTotalyUniqueName
host: testapp1withtotalyuniquename
disk_quota: 1024M
```

I have already checked this link: http://blog.ibmjstart.net/2015/10/27/a-play-scala-server-running-on-ibm-bluemix/
Any ideas how to fix it?

Output from console:

```
2015-11-03T18:30:50.70+0200 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Liberty buildpack is done creating the droplet
2015-11-03T18:30:51.31+0200 [STG/0]      ERR 
2015-11-03T18:31:00.89+0200 [STG/115]    OUT -----> Uploading droplet (91M)
2015-11-03T18:31:11.91+0200 [DEA/115]    OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid b634d704-85f2-4e42-b559-985de67c90ae
2015-11-03T18:31:30.09+0200 [App/0]      OUT [info] - play.api.Play - Application started (Prod)
2015-11-03T18:31:30.23+0200 [App/0]      OUT [info] - play.core.server.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
2015-11-03T18:32:22.04+0200 [DEA/115]    ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2015-11-03T18:32:22.05+0200 [API/7]      OUT App instance exited with guid b634d704-85f2-4e42-b559-985de67c90ae payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"b634d704-85f2-4e42-b559-985de67c90ae", "version"=>"1b3e8d86-501a-4679-9104-9a9dea063ccd", "instance"=>"19d1570c9865486985c6f159a90233dd", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>-1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1446568342}
2015-11-03T18:32:22.07+0200 [App/0]      ERR 
2015-11-03T18:32:52.39+0200 [DEA/112]    OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid b634d704-85f2-4e42-b559-985de67c90ae
2015-11-03T18:33:04.31+0200 [App/0]      OUT [info] - play.api.Play - Application started (Prod)
2015-11-03T18:33:04.43+0200 [App/0]      OUT [info] - play.core.server.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
```

Comment: Can you please run `cf logs TestApp1WithTotallyUniqueName --recent` and post the output here?

Comment: Here you are @AlexdaSilva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And this line was missing in manifest.yml:

```
buildpack: java_buildpack
```